# Codeigniter : $this->db->_error_message() message returns NULL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I have a query which gives me perfect results. But I need to send the mysql errors (if any) to UI. So I deliberately change column name to `blah_text`.

```
$qID = 13
$this->db->select('id AS optionID, blah_text AS option, is_correct AS isCorrect');
$oQuery = $this->db->get_where('xq_options', array('question_id' => $qID));
if($oQuery){
    $qnaArray['options'] = $oQuery->result_array();
}
else{
    //$qnaArray['error'] = $this->db->_error_message();
    echo "Error: " .  $this->db->_error_message();
}
```

All the get is `Error:`

I tried using native mysqli function `mysqli_error($oQuery);` but same O/P

Note: I have set `'db_debug' => FALSE` in database config files. If I set it to TRUE, i do get the CI error message

`Error Number: 1054 Unknown column 'blah_text' in 'field list' SELECT id AS optionID, blah_text AS option, is_correct AS isCorrect`

How do I capture sql errors in a variable and send it to UI like `$qnaArray['error']`

EDIT: `'db_debug'` is currently set to FALSE. I want the error message to be set in a variable. Not echoed on the screen.

Comment: If you are getting error using `'db_debug'=> TRUE`. What is the problem?

Comment: @SagarKhatri I get errors on the page CI styled. I need to send it as a webservice json to UI so that I can be displayed properly.

Comment: Which clients are going to use your WebService? Android,iPhone or in frontend through JS?

Comment: @SagarKhatri iPad and JS

Comment: I think stripping the tag and getting the message text will be enough. You can use `$qnaArray['error'] = strip_tags($this->db->_error_message());`.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. `$this->db->_error_message()` is empty

Comment: Have you changed `db_debug` value with `TRUE`?

Comment: It's FALSE. If I set it to TRUE I see errors on the screen. Not in that variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93860/discussion-between-sagar-khatri-and-enemetch).

Answer (score 1):

`$this->db->_error_message();` will not execute when selecting data.

Use this

```
$qID = '13';
$query = $this->db->query(
            "SELECT id AS optionID, blah_text AS option, is_correct AS isCorrect 
             FROM table_name WHERE xq_options = $qID");
$result = $query->result_array();
$count = count($result);

if (!empty($count)) {
    return $result;
}
else{
    echo "No Data Found";
}
```

Comment: I can use `$query->num_rows()` instead. Thats not the point. I need to see the MySQL error message. `Unknown column 'blah_text' in 'field list' SELECT id AS optionID, blah_text AS option, is_correct AS isCorrect`

Comment: Use my query and check

Comment: Your query works. But I either get results or I get "No Data Found", What I need is the error message.

Comment: `Unknown column 'blah_text' in 'field list' SELECT id AS optionID, blah_text AS option, is_correct AS isCorrect`

Comment: @eNeMetcH ahh use this inside else `$this->db->_error_message();`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$e = $this->db->error(); // Gets the last error that has occured
$num = $e['code'];
$mess = $e['message'];
```

Info available in https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html search "Handling Errors"

Comment: Actually the documentation says; " the error() method will return an **array** containing its code and message". So, the way you get the code and message is

`$error['code'] `
`$error['message']`

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of this:**

```
if($oQuery)
{
   $qnaArray['options'] = $oQuery->result_array();
}
else{
//$qnaArray['error'] = $this->db->_error_message();
echo "Error: " .  $this->db->_error_message();
}
```

**try using this:**

```
if($oQuery->num_rows()>0)
{
   $qnaArray['options'] = $oQuery->result_array();
}
else{
//$qnaArray['error'] = $this->db->_error_message();
echo "Error: " .  $this->db->_error_message();
}
```

Comment: I got this: `Fatal error:  Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean` But a CI error message. Not from `$this->db->_error_message();`

Comment: use this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923382/how-to-catch-db-errors-in-codeigniter-php

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$this->db->simple_query('SELECT `id` FROM `customers`')) {
   $error = $this->db->error();
}

$data['db_error_message'] = 'Error [' . $error['code'] . '] ' . $error['message'];
```

From the documentation on page https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#handling-errors

In your view, this code prints out a message like this;

**DB Error Message : Error [1146] Table 'mydb.customers' doesn't exist**

Similarly, your code prints out the same result.

```
$qID = 13;
$this->db->select('id AS `optionID`, blah_text AS `option`, is_correct AS `isCorrect`');
$oQuery = $this->db->get_where('xq_options', array('question_id' => $qID));

if (!$oQuery) {
   $err = $this->db->error();
}
$data['err_message'] = 'Error [' . $err['code'] . '] ' . $err['message'];
```

prints; 
**Err Message : Error [1146] Table 'mydb.xq_options' doesn't exist**

I did not create tables, so my messages are 'table not found' error messages instead of 'column not found'.

I guess this is what you wanted.